# Reading from a file and store it in an 2d-array c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I need to read some lines from a file and store it in an 2d-array and also to print it to the console.

The Input looks similar to this (just with 30 rows):

```
000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000
000000111000000000000000000000
000000000000011100011000000000
000000000000001000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000
001111110000000000000100000000
000111000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000010000000000
```

But before printing it to the console. I need to change every 0 to Space   and every 1 to a `*`, and then store it in an array and printing it out.

My current code looks like this:

```
ifstream fp("preset.txt");
if (fp.is_open()) {
        while (getline(fp, str)) {
            cout << str << '\n';
        }
        fp.close();
    }
    else {
        cout << "Unable to open file";
    }
```

But the output is very confusing, because it consists almost only of *..

Comment: You open the file then do nothing with it. Are you asking how to use an [`ifstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream)?

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run this program, one line at a time, what did you see? And what would be the purpose of copying `tmpArr` to `arr`, like that, only to compare each copied value? Why can't you compare `tmpArr`'s contents, directly?

Comment: okay yes sorry, I had a complete wrong understand of ifstream. Now I got it that far, that the normal lines are shown, but its unclear for me how I can replace the 0 to ' ' and 1 to '*'. I edited my post to the new code (without storing it into that array).

Comment: The previous version of your code demonstrated that you know how to use `for` loops and `if` statements. That's all that's needed to accomplish this task. What exactly is unclear to you? Try to write down a logical algorithm for doing this, in short, brief, logical sentences in plain English. Then, just take what you've written down and translate it directly into C++. Mission accomplished.

Comment: Why do you need to store into an array?

Comment: I need to save it to a 2d array so I can continue working with  that array afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, you are inputting an array of 1's and zeros and `transform`ing the zeros into   and the ones into `*`.

Here's an example:

```
std::string    row;
while (std::getline(fp, row))
{
  const size_t length = row.length();
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
  {
     if (row[i] == '0') row[i] = ' ';
     if (row[i] == '1') row[i] = '*';
  }
  std::cout << row << "\n";
}
```

If you want, you could write a transformation function:

```
char map_transform(const char& a)
{
    if (a == '0') return ' ';
    if (a == '1') return '*';
    return a;
}
```

and simplify your code:

```
while (std::getline(fp, row))
{
    std::transform(row.begin(), row.end(),
                   row.begin(),
                   map_transform);
    std::cout << row << "\n";
}
```